# Only predict a single time-series-sample within a batch using predict() or predict_on_batch()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, predict

In stackoverflow-questions like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911321/why-does-prediction-needs-batch-size-in-keras) I read about the `batch_size`-parameter in Keras' `predict()`-method or in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972565/what-is-the-difference-between-the-predict-and-predict-on-batch-methods-of-a-ker) about the difference of `predict()` and `predict_on_batch()`.

Anyhow, my question was not answered in them. I understand the concept of the `batch_size` and that I can predict a single batch with `predict_on_batch()`. But what I want to achieve is predicting *a single sample from a batch with multiple samples.* The prediction in this case is a time-series prediction.

***An example***

Let's asume I've got a batch of `shape(2,5,1)` for the samples as well as targets. These batches are fed to a model like this:

```py
sequence_size      = 5
number_of_features = 1
input              = (sequence_size, number_of_features)
batch_size         = 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(100, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=input, batch_size=2, name="GRU"))
model.add(GRU(1, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=input, batch_size=batch_size, name="GRU2"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()

#Summary-output:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
GRU (GRU)                    (2, 5, 100)               30600     
_________________________________________________________________
GRU2 (GRU)                   (2, 5, 1)                 306       
=================================================================
Total params: 30,906
Trainable params: 30,906
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I fit this model and predict something in shape of a single batch `(2, 5, 1)`, the `predict()` works.

```py
def generator(data, batch_size, sequence_size, num_features):
    """Simple generator"""
    while True:
        for i in range(len(data) - (sequence_size * batch_size + sequence_size) + 1):
            start = i
            end   = i + (sequence_size * batch_size)
            
            yield data[start : end].reshape(batch_size, sequence_size, num_features), \
                    data[end - ((sequence_size * batch_size) - sequence_size) : end + sequence_size].reshape(batch_size, sequence_size, num_features)

#Task: Predict the continuation of a linear range
data = np.arange(100)
hist = model.fit_generator(
                generator=generator(data, batch_size, sequence_size, num_features),
                steps_per_epoch=total_batches,
                epochs=200,
                shuffle=False
            )


to_predict = np.asarray([[np.asarray([x]) for x in range(105-sequence_size*batch_size,105,1)]]).reshape(batch_size, sequence_size, num_features)
correct_result    = np.asarray([100,101,102,103,104])
print( model.predict(to_predict).flatten()[0:sequence_size] )

#Prediction output something close to what I want (correct_result)
[ 99.92908 100.95854 102.32129 103.28584 104.20213 ]
```

For the sake of a better understanding; the generator-output per batch looks like:

```py
(array([[ [0],[1],[2],[3],[4] ], [ [5],[6],[7],[8],[9] ]]),   #Sample of shape (2, 5, 1), meaning two sequences of length 5 with one feature
 array([[[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]], [[10],[11],[12],[13],[14]]]))  #Target of shape (2, 5, 1), meaning two sequences of length 5 with one feature
```

**But what I want to predict is a shape like `(1, 5, 1)`**. The reason: A single batch contains two sequences (hence two samples) of respectively 5 time-steps. When I provide a shape of `(2, 5, 1)` this means that I have to use two sequences for a prediction and `predict()` also returns the prediction for the following two sequences (since the training-target was also in shape of `(2, 5, 1)`).

What I can do so far is to input a sequence that shall be predicted (in `shape(1, 5, 1)` with an output of `(1, 5, 1)`) in `predict_on_batch()` and only return the first result (`predict_on_batch()` also returns a shape of `(2, 5, 1)`, but both samples in there yield the same predicted values).

```py
to_predict = np.asarray([[np.asarray([x]) for x in range(95,100,1)]])
correct    = np.asarray([100,101,102,103,104])
print( model.predict_on_batch(to_predict)[0].flatten() )

#Output:
[ 99.92908 100.95854 102.32129 103.28584 104.20213 ]
```

As can be seen, the output is the same as with `predict()`, but I only inputted a single sample from a batch in `shape(1, 5, 1)`. Additionally, `predict_on_batch()` did not throw any error. Since the results are the same, there is obviously no reason to provide an entire batch (in my example a batch only contains of two samples, but of course this can be higher in real tasks).

Thus, I got a workaround for my question. But I have the feeling that I'm missing a method that allows this without workarounds.

**So my question is**: ***How can I predict a singe sample from a single batch, whereby this prediciton also only outputs a single prediction?***

---

**Edit:**

I know about [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/) tutorial on machinelearningmastery.com. Anyhow, this also just provides workarounds (I also consider copying weights to a new network a workaround).

Comment: This is my $1000000 question too. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani Unfortunately not... And I think its one of the major drawbacks of `Keras`. Maybe we should start a bounty on this, hoping somebody does know anything

Comment: I believe it's not possible. We have to be "batch-oriented" in both training and predicting. In my case batch size is 32. This means I cannot do either more than or less than 32 predictions at a time. Since I only need one prediction, I use predictions_result[-1, 0] to get the last one (my desired one) where predictions_result = model.predict(X_data) in which X_data has the form batch_size x time_step x number_of_features.